# Kafka producer properties setting

Tags: apache-kafka

I set the `acks=all` in the *produer.properties* file which is present in the kafka broker's config folder. However this change is not reflecting, even after i restarted the broker and reconnected from the producer.

Should this be set only in the Kafka client? Then what is the use of *producer.properties* file in the Kafka broker config folder. The same-way consumer properties are also not getting reflected.

Can Somebody help on this. Also how the configuration parameter's precedence happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you need to do? `acks=all` just ensure that all followers receive the message and your message is saved successfully. do you have any problem with storing messages?

Comment: where to set this property. I set this in the producer.properties file in the kafka broker config folder instead of setting in the client code . This change is not reflecting at the producer side

Answer (score 0):

You set `acks=all` at producer level. The producer client you are creating to connect to broker is where you set this property.
The `producer.properties` or `consumer.properties` is a quickstart file. Take it as an example on how you should create a properties file.